# Is it possible to add a file to a zip stream?

Tags: stream, zip, addition, tar, bsdtar

Let's suppose I download a zip archive, and I mean something like adding some file on the fly to the data stream, avoiding usage of a temp file:

```
wget http://example.com/archive.zip -O - | zipadder -f myfile.txt | pv
```

I read somewhere that bsdtar can manipulate such streams.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be hard on RAM, as it needs you to manipulate the zip structure entirely in memory. That said, it should be possible to write `zipadder` in python, using `StringIO` to manipulate a memory-backed file-like object read from stdin like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import zipfile
import sys
import StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO(sys.stdin.read())  # read buffer from stdin
f = zipfile.ZipFile(s, 'a')
f.write('myfile.txt')  # add file to buffer
f.close()
print s.getvalue()  # write buffer to stdout
```

Comment: Thx, meanwhile I managed to find out a faster solution:

"curl http://example.com/archive.zip|bsdtar -cf - @- |bsdtar -c -f - newfile.txt @-|bsdtar -cf - --format zip @- |pv"

It first converts the zip stream to tar stream, add new file(s) and then convert the stream back to zip format. However I don't know how to add more than one file at the same time, unless repeating the 3rd part of this construction.

Comment: even shorter:

"curl http://example.com/archive.zip|bsdtar --format zip -c -f - newfile.txt @- | pv"